# calculate total minutes of it's own ID in db table

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am trying to show some stats given date ranges.  In table rows there are many ID's and trying to calculate total minutes of it's own ID.

Currently returns values as below:

```
{"id":"25","minute":13}
{"id":"17","minute":12}
{"id":"16","minute":10}
{"id":"17","minute":10}
{"id":"16","minute":4}
{"id":"34","minute":5}
{"id":"17","minute":21}
{"id":"30","minute":12}
{"id":"30","minute":13}
{"id":"30","minute":50}
```

Controller

```
public function actionStats()  {
    if (isset($_POST['begin'], $_POST['end'])) {
        $begin = strtotime($_POST['begin']);
        $end = strtotime($_POST['end']);

        $Criteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $Criteria->condition = "created >= $begin and  created <= $end and status=1";
        $transcripts = Transcripts::model()->findAll($Criteria);

        foreach($transcripts as $transcript)  {
            $op = $transcript->opID;
            $minute = $transcript->ended - $transcript->created;

            echo json_encode(array("id" => $op, "minute" => floor($minute/60)));
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: To add one integer to another use `+` arithmetic operator

Comment: `SELECT id, SUM(minute) AS total FROM tablename GROUP BY id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd modify your code to look like:

```
public function actionStats()
{

    if (isset($_POST['begin'], $_POST['end']))
    {
        $begin = strtotime($_POST['begin']);
        $end = strtotime($_POST['end']);

        $Criteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $Criteria->condition = "created >= $begin and  created <= $end and status=1";
        $transcripts = Transcripts::model()->findAll($Criteria);

        $transcriptTotals = array();
        foreach($transcripts as $transcript)
        {

            $op = $transcript->opID;
            $minute = $transcript->ended - $transcript->created;
            if (array_key_exists($op, $transcriptTotals)) {
                $transcriptTotals[$op] += floor($minute/60);
            } else {
                $transcriptTotals[$op] = floor($minute/60);
            }
        }
        echo json_encode($transcriptTotals);
    }       

}
```

This should result in output that looks like:

```
{'1':'2', 'id':'sumOfMinutes', etc}
```

If your JSON needs to be like you specified above, you would have code like:

```
foreach ($transcriptTotals as $id=>$sum) {
    echo json_encode(array('id'=>$id, 'minutes'=>$sum));
}
```

Comment: got an error Undefined index: 25 line $transcriptTotals[$op] += floor($minute/60);

Comment: fixed it . . . error would happen the first time through as $op didn't exist yet in the array.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding it up in the MySQL query already? E.g. with the `SUM` function:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html